# Boon Json unable to desrialize Enums by common interface

Tags: java, json, enums, boon

I'm trying to serialize and deserialize through Boon Json a simple `Map <Resistance, Double> map = new HashMap()`, where `Resistance` is an interface implemented only by two enum.

```
public interface Resistance {}

public enum Condition implements Resistance{
    BURN, SLEEP, PARALYZED, CONFUSE;
}

public enum Element implements Resistance{
    FIRE, ICE, EARTH, AIR;
}
```

after adding some value the serialization seems to work fine:

```
map.put(Element.FIRE, 1.1);
map.put(Condition.BURN, 0.2);
System.out.println("Fire resistance: " + map.get(Element.FIRE));
System.out.println("Burn resistance: " + map.map.get(Condition.BUR));

ObjectMapper mapper =  JsonFactory.create();
String dst = mapper.toJson(manager);
System.out.println(dst);
```

Output:

```
Fire resistance: 1.1
Burn resistance: 0.2
{"map":{"FIRE":1.1,"BURNED":0.2}}
```

The problem occurs during deserialization, (I think) the parser fails to associate the enumerator with its class. And so I get:

```
map = mapper.readValue(dst, map.getClass()) ;

System.out.println("Fire resistance: " + manager.get(Element.FIRE));
System.out.println("Burn resistance: " + manager.get(Condition.BURN));
```

Output:

```
Fire resistance: null
Burn resistance: null
{"map":{"":0.2}}
```

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am editing my answer:

//Wrong as map.getClass() returned actual implementation of class

`Map map2 =  mapper.readValue(dst, map.getClass()) ;`

//returned correct map

`Map map2 =  mapper.readValue(dst,Map.class) ;`

Also change your code that prints to :

```
System.out.println("Fire resistance: " + manager.get(Element.FIRE.toString()));
System.out.println("Burn resistance: " + manager.get(Condition.BURN.toString()));
```

Comment: So I should use a Map with String as key, or use `valueOf()` every time

Comment: now i get a `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Enum` I still need to use toString

Comment: yes you are right. Old one still is needed. Somehow it got removed while editing my answer

Comment: Thanks, everything works. But when my Map is inside another class I can not do this trick.

Comment: @GiuseppeCianci in another class e.g?

Comment: For example, I could have the map in a class that models a shield.
So doing, when I do `myShield = mapper.readValue (dst, MyShieldImp.class)` I have the same problem again, and get an empty map.

Comment: You always pass Map.class there instead of  MyShieldImp.class or anything else.